# youtube app - is there a way to resume play back

Tags: youtube, android-tv

I have an android set top box call Pivos Xios. It is running android 4.0.4. This is plugin my 1080p TV. This device is great because for 100$ you get to have a browser on your TV and all the play store app you already purchased are available.

So I have installed the youtube app which works great. I logged in my account and get to have my history and my watch later videos, that is just awesome. I was just wondering if there was a way to resume playback of a video that I stop/paused for a later view.

I know I can do that with the XBMC app and the youtube plugin installed, but the interface is much less intuitive an user friendly that I prefer to use the youtube app directly.

On my PC, sometimes (I haven't found what triggers it), when I reload a page of a youtube video I've already been watching, it is sometimes cropped from where I stopped it. There is a bracket added to the timeline.

I'm looking to have a similar functionnality over my youtube app on android.

Any advices are welcomed.